# Compute dissimilarity between each pairs of categorical unit in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

From a contingency `matrix`, we can compute the dissimilarity between each pair of rows and then convert the output as a `data.frame`.

For example, with the Bray-Curtis distance, we can have:

```
# Generate matrix -------------------------------------------------------------
set.seed(1)
ex <- matrix(data = round(runif(100000), 1), nrow = 1000, ncol = 100)
rownames(ex) <- paste0("row", 1:nrow(ex))
colnames(ex) <- paste0("col", 1:ncol(ex))
ex[1:5, 1:5]
     col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
row1  0.3  0.5  0.9  0.8  0.2
row2  0.4  0.7  1.0  0.5  0.5
row3  0.6  0.4  0.9  0.2  0.0
row4  0.9  1.0  0.4  0.4  0.5
row5  0.2  0.1  0.2  0.8  0.9

# Dissimilarity ---------------------------------------------------------------
# Example of Bray-Curtis
library(ecodist)
bray <- bcdist(ex, rmzero = FALSE)
bray <- as.matrix(bray)
bray[upper.tri(bray)] <- NA
diag(bray) <- NA

# Convert distance matrix into data.frame
bray <- reshape2::melt(bray, varnames = c("id1", "id2"))
# Remove NAs
bray <- bray[complete.cases(bray), ]

head(bray)
   id1  id2     value
2 row2 row1 0.2767599
3 row3 row1 0.3541247
4 row4 row1 0.3588235
5 row5 row1 0.3935618
6 row6 row1 0.2948328
7 row7 row1 0.4045643
```

Now, I am interested to know if it's possible to get the same output `bray` (i.e. a `data frame` having 3 columns) from a long format `data frame` as an input.
For example, if we convert the example `matrix` provided above as:

```
# From a data.frame -----------------------------------------------------------
ex_df <- reshape2::melt(ex)
colnames(ex_df) <- c("row", "col", "value")
```

is it possible to get the same `bray` output containing the Bray-Curtis dissimilarity between each pair of rows?
I bet efficient `dplyr` or `data.table` solutions exist.

Answer (score 0):

Would this achieve what you are after. Basically, it's just rearranging long format data into matrix-like dataframe and calculating BC from it. I imagine your actual dataset come in long format.

```
library(tidyverse)

BC_dist <- ex_df %>% 
  spread(2,3) %>% 
  column_to_rownames("row") %>% 
  bcdist(rmzero = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

`ecodist::bcdist` calls a C implementation of Bray Curtis distance which is pretty hard to beat in terms of timing. However, it is single-threaded and hence, a possible approach is to parallelize the calculations using OpenMP via Rcpp:

`bcd.cpp`:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix bcd(NumericMatrix m) {
    int i, j, k, nr = m.nrow(), nc = m.ncol();
    NumericMatrix res(nr, nr);
    double ms, sum;

    #pragma omp parallel for private(ms, sum, j, k)
    for (i = 0; i < nr - 1; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < nr; j++) {
            ms = 0;
            sum = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < nc; k++) {
                if (m(i, k) < m(j, k)) {
                    ms += m(i, k);
                } else {
                    ms += m(j, k);
                }
                sum += m(i, k) + m(j, k);
            }
            res(j, i) = 1 - 2 * ms / sum;
        }
    }

    return(res);
}
```

timing code:

```
set.seed(0L)
library(ecodist)

nr <- 10000
nc <- 100
m <- matrix(round(runif(nr*nc), 1L), nrow=nr, ncol=nc)

library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("bcd.cpp")

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times=3L,
    a1 <- bcdist(m, rmzero = FALSE),
    a2 <- bcd(m))

all.equal(as.vector(a1), a2[lower.tri(a2)])
#[1] TRUE
```

timings:

```
Unit: seconds
                            expr       min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 a1 <- bcdist(m, rmzero = FALSE) 24.348883 24.42572 24.496605 24.502548 24.570466 24.638384     3
                    a2 <- bcd(m)  8.365889  8.50686  8.563122  8.647831  8.661739  8.675646     3
```